# SSRS RowNumber counting a Groups in the report sequentially

Tags: reporting-services

Here is what I need to achieve. This is for an import into a Purchasing system.

Created an SSRS report that works fine. Im missing one more step to finish
 it. I'll try to explain what was achieved and what remains to be achieved.

**Achieved:**

**LINEID**     **LNARR2**

1              751 
 1              793 
 1              804 
 2              804 
 3              804 
 4              804 
 1              807 
 2              807 
 3              807

The avobe are 4 payments. payment id is represented by: **"LNARR2"** (751, 793, 804 and 807). **"LINEID"** counts the number of lines pertaining to a group (purchase)

**In SSRS this was achieved by**

1. creating a group, name: "LNARR2_GRP" and Group On: "LNARR2"
2. expression for "LINEID" `=RowNumber("LNARR2_GRP")`

**Remains to be achieved**

Following on from the example above. I need to add the Document ID **(DOCID)**. Similar to LINEID but to be represented as follows:

**DOCID**  **LINEID**     **LNARR2**

1     1              751 
 2     1              793 
 3     1              804 
 3     2              804 
 3     3              804 
 3     4              804 
 4     1              807 
 4     2              807 
 4     3              807

The above indicates that:

- Document ID **"1"** has one description line
- Document ID **"3"** has four lines in its description

**Question:**
What is the expression for **"DOCID"**? to get the sequential count per group as per the example above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
declare @t table (LINEID int, LNARR2 int)
insert into @t
values
( 1 ,     751 ),
( 1 ,     793 ),
( 1 ,     804 ),
( 2 ,     804 ),
( 3 ,     804 ),
 (4 ,     804 ),
 (1 ,     807 ),
 (2 ,     807 ),
 (3 ,     807 )


select  s.docid,t.lineid,t.lnarr2
from    @t t
join
(select lnarr2, row_number() over (order by lnarr2) docid from @t group by lnarr2) s
on      s.lnarr2 = t.lnarr2
```

Comment: **Thank you** for the SQL code. The output is 100% correct. Now, how do I translate that into an SSRS expression?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I incorporated your suggestion (**code**) into the SSRS query and it is now finished.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this =RunningValue(Fields!DOCID.Value,count,"GroupName")